# Matching Polygons in a list of Polygons

Tags: plotting, pattern-matching, geometry

In the process of creating a more complex algorithm, I've stumbled upon some strange behaviour I am trying to understand with my matching function.

What I'm expecting to see on the right hand side is the orange overlaid geometry to have no exact matches with the old geometry below. However, one can see below, toward the bottom, one polygon has been highlighted though no changes have been made. The problem appears to be either with the `Position` function or the `Complement` function. However, even after rewriting a bit of the code to do a numerical match, the difference is still not being picked up. What's the best way to address this problem?

[image]

```
ClearAll[matchingLogic, r, newpoly, oldpoly, diffpoly]
r = RandomReal[1000, {15, 2}];
oldpoly = MeshPrimitives[DelaunayMesh[RandomSample[r, 13]], 2];
newpoly = MeshPrimitives[DelaunayMesh[RandomSample[r, 13]], 2];

matchingLogic[old_, newpoly_] := Module[{match, oldgeo, newgeo},
  (*Sorts points to consistently match numerically *)   
  oldgeo = SortBy[
    SortBy[#, First] & /@ 
     Cases[old, Polygon[x_] :> x, Infinity],
    #[[1, 2]] &];
  newgeo = SortBy[
    SortBy[#, First] & /@ 
     Cases[newpoly, Polygon[x_] :> x, Infinity],
    #[[1, 2]] &];
  (* Finds position of matching new geometry *)
  match = Flatten[
    Position[
       oldgeo, # 
       ] & /@ newgeo
    ];
  match
  ]

var = matchingLogic[oldpoly, newpoly];
diffpoly = Complement[oldpoly, oldpoly[[var]] ];
```

**Graphics**

```
oldcolors = 
  RandomSample[
   ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"] /@ 
    Range[0, 1, (1/(Length@oldpoly - 1))]];
newcolors = 
  RandomSample[
   ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"] /@ 
    Range[0, 1, (1/(Length@newpoly - 1))]];
diff = {Opacity[0.4], Orange, Directive[EdgeForm[Black]], diffpoly};
pts = {AbsolutePointSize[10], Opacity[0.8], Orange, Point@r};

gA = Graphics[{
    MapThread[
     List, {Table[Opacity[0.6], Length@oldpoly], 
      Table[Directive[EdgeForm[Black]], Length@oldpoly], oldcolors, 
      oldpoly}], pts},
   ImageSize -> 300,
   PlotLabel -> "Old Geometry"];
gB = Graphics[{
    MapThread[
     List, {Table[Opacity[0.6], Length@diffpoly], 
      Table[Directive[EdgeForm[Black]], Length@diffpoly], diffcolors, 
      diffpoly}], pts},
   ImageSize -> 300,
   PlotLabel -> "Geometry that will change"];
gC = Graphics[{
    MapThread[
     List, {Table[Opacity[0.6], Length@newpoly], 
      Table[Directive[EdgeForm[Black]], Length@newpoly], newcolors, 
      newpoly}], pts, diff},
   ImageSize -> 300,
   PlotLabel -> "Old Geometry with changes overlaid"];
Row[{gA, gB, gC}]
```

Comment: Can you put in some `(*...*)` comments. It's a bit difficult to understand what the `matchingLogic` function does line by line. If you need to match polygons, can't you just use `SortBy[poly1[[1]], First] == SortBy[poly2[[1]], First]` ?

Comment: There are a couple different ways to match but I needed a method that saved the position of the original because its part of a more complex algorithm and has other information and parameters associated with the position that need to be computed and translated.

Comment: This would be much simpler: `matchingLogic[oldpolygons_, newpolygons_] := 
 Flatten[Position[oldpolygons, p_Polygon /; RegionEqual[p, #]] & /@ 
   newpolygons]`

Answer (score 2):

Credit goes to user **flinty** in the comments who suggested a more concise and accurate way to find the matches with `RegionEqual`. It also thankfully appears to correct the matching issue. Still don't know what the root cause was but happy to have learned a way to use `RegionEqual` in a pattern conditional.

```
matchingLogic[oldpolygons_, newpolygons_] := 
 Flatten[Position[oldpolygons, p_Polygon /; RegionEqual[p, #]] & /@ 
   newpolygons]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]